# Java Regular expression - find strings with no vowels

Tags: java, regex

I have a list of words and I have to output the number of words with no vowels in them.  I have this so far

```
String matchString = "[^aeiou]"
for(String s: list) if(s.matches(matchString.toLowerCase())) {
        System.out.println(s);
        numMatches++;
    }
```

I'm more worried that the reg expression is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one does the trick for me:

```
[^aeiou]+$
```

Also you should lowercase the string, not the expression:

```
if (s.toLowerCase().matches(matchString))
```

Comment: It's looking good, but what to change if I also want to only characters without vowels.

Answer (score 5):

Change regex to

```
[^aeiou]+ 
        ^-- important part
```

to test if string is build from *one or more non vowel characters*. Currently you are just checking if stirng is build from one character which is not `a` `e` `i` `o` `u`.

You can also make your regex case insensitive by adding `(?i)` flag at start. This way characters used in regex will represent its lower and upper case

```
(?i)[^aeiou]+
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you put the regex into lowercase rather than the String you're actually testing. You want

```
if (s.toLowerCase().matches(matchString)){...}
```

Also, I believe your regex should be `"[^aeiou]*"`, so you can match all the characters in the word.

Answer (score 0):

import java.util.regex.*;

public class Vowels {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "hello";
    int count = 0;
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[aeiou]");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
    while (m.find()) {
        count++;
        System.out.println(m.start() + "...." + m.group());
    }
    System.out.println("number of vowels found in the string ="+count);
}
```

}

Answer (score -1):

For me only `/^[^aeiou]+$/` did the job.